# cardinality of coset is same with cardinality of subgroup.

Tags: group-theory

Let $(G,*)$ be a group and $\emptyset \ne H \subseteq G$, with $|H| = m < \infty$. Show that for all $g\in G$, $|g*H|=m$.

How to show that $H$ is subgroup of $G$? Since $a*b$ is not necessarily in $H$ for all $a,b \in H$ and $H$ is an arbitrary subset of $G$.

Comment: With a considerable amount of lies, I guess.

Comment: Though some would say that you can not only make do with just one lie, but also with any lie whatsoever.

Comment: @Gae.S. Sorry? What is lie?

Comment: A false statement made with deliberate intent to deceive; an intentional untruth; a falsehood

Answer (score 1):

The equality $|gH| = |H|$ holds even when $H$ is not a subgroup, and even if $H$ is empty. Just observe that the map $h \to gh$ defines a bijection from $H$ to $gH$. Can you see why?

Comment: Why that's holds even when $H$ isn't subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Because there is bijection from $f$ that you define above?

Comment: It is surjective by construction. It remains to prove it is injective. If $gh = gh'$, can you deduce that $h = h'$?

Comment: By definition, $f$ is surjective. Let $h,h' \in H$ and assume $f(h)=f(h')$. Then, $gh = gh' \Leftrightarrow h = h'$ by the cancellation law.

Comment: Exactly. This solves your question.

Comment: Great. But, I still confuse why $f$ is surjective just from considering its definition?

Comment: $gH = \{gh \mid h \in H\} = \{f(h) \mid h \in H\} = f(H)$.

Comment: Great, Sir. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Consider the function $f:H\rightarrow g*H$ defined by $$f(h)=g*h$$
where $h\in H$.
Prove by definition that $f$ is a bijection.
This will show that $|g*H|=|H|=m$.

Comment: How to show the surjection? Is that come from the definition of $f$?

Comment: @user795084 Yes. Let $x\in g*H$. Then $x=g*h$ for some $h\in H$. Therefore $x=g*h=f(h)$. This shows that $f$ is a surjection.

Comment: Great. Thanks Sir!